# basic pyinstaller on MacOS X

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I am trying to get `pyinstaller` to work with a python script of mine which fails. So I tried a very basic script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *
x=linspace(0,2*pi,200)
plot(x,sin(x))
show()
```

But this also fails with the error message below. I'm on a up-to-date Mountain Lion and am using enthought python if that matters. I call it with `python pyinstaller.py --onefile ../testpyinst.py` when being in the pyinstaller directory and the complete output is here:

```
23 INFO: wrote xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/testpyinst/testpyinst.spec
54 INFO: UPX is not available.
1263 INFO: checking Analysis
1337 INFO: checking PYZ
1350 INFO: checking PKG
1350 INFO: building because out00-PKG.toc missing or bad
1350 INFO: building PKG out00-PKG.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 91, in <module>
    main()
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 86, in main
    run_build(opts, spec_file)
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 50, in run_build
    PyInstaller.build.main(spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1625, in main
    build(specfile, buildpath)
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 1582, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/testpyinst/testpyinst.spec", line 16, in <module>
    console=True )
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 987, in __init__
    crypt=self.crypt)
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 880, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 315, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/build.py", line 933, in assemble
    archive.build(self.name, mytoc)
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/archive.py", line 202, in build
    self.save_toc(tocpos)
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/carchive.py", line 250, in save_toc
    tocstr = self.toc.tobinary()
  File "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/carchive.py", line 79, in tobinary
    nmlen+entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, nm+pad))
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a string
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, you'll probably need to post more of the traceback so that people can see where the error begins (that error is not from the script you've written and posted).

Comment: Thanks, I added the complete output now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you successfully built anything with `pyinstaller`?  I suggest you write a simpler code that has no external dependencies,

```
print "Hello World!"
```

or

```
f = open('test.txt','w')
f.write("Hello World!")
f.close()
```

try to import a standard library module, say `math`:

```
import math
x = 10.0
y = math.sqrt(x)
print "square_root({}) = {}".format(x,y)
```

Next try using `numpy` that simply prints `sin(x)` instead of trying to plot it.

```
from numpy import *
x = linspace(0,2*pi,20)
print sin(x)
```

If that works, perhaps instead of `show`ing the plot, try to `savefig` and see if the error has something to do with attempting to display the figure.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *
x=linspace(0,2*pi,200)
plot(x,sin(x))
savefig("/tmp/testfig.png")
```

If that still doesn't work it could be an issue with your matplotlib backend.  Use a simpler/more standard one:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from numpy import *
x=linspace(0,2*pi,200)
plot(x,sin(x))
savefig("/tmp/testfig.png")
```

Comment: No, even with the simplest first option `print sin(x)`, it doesn't work and gives the same traceback as before.

Comment: I added another step: see if standard library modules can be imported.  It's possible your problem lies in the installation of numpy.

Comment: Ok, one part of the problem was the option `--onefile`. Once I removed that, I got most of the above working. For plotting something, I need to add the option `--windowed`, this works as it should, however for the interactive use with `show()` and `matplotlib.use("WxAgg")`, I do get the window, but it crashes as soon as my mouse enters the figure window. The error message is `MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.dylib`

Comment: I believe we've now moved beyond my expertise, sorry I can't help more.  Now that you have it running and have a different bug altogether, perhaps you have enough information to post a more detailed question elsewhere (perhaps these folks: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/pyinstaller )

Comment: @JohnSmith Did you ever get any resolution for this problem?  I am experiencing a similar issue with matplotlib and PyInstaller, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

What I did is open this file `xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/pyinstaller-2.0/PyInstaller/loader/carchive.py`, and add several `print()` after line 79. And I found nm+pad is not recognized as a string. It is kinda of strange though. I am using windows 7, `print()` shows that `nm=kernel32` and `pad = ''`.

Now talk about my temp solution:

```
rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's', nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, nm + pad))
```

----change to----->

```
try:
    rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's', nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, nm + pad))
except:
    ss = str(nm + pad)
    rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's', nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, ss))
```

Not sure if it is a robust solution, but it works in mine. I believe you can use similar technique to figure out yours. BTW, I am using pyinstaller2.1 + python2.7.6. The command is 
`pyinstaller -F MyApp.py --hidden-import=scipy.special._ufuncs_cxx`

Comment: To clarify: the changed lines of code here solved the problem where your executable crashes whenever you mouse over the graph?  I was able to find this line, but unfortunately changing it had no effect for me. Is the hidden-import flag relevant to this issue?

Comment: Never have mouse - over issue. Above i am trying to solve struct error of 's' in original post.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the same as described in hxu’s comment; changing

```
rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's', nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, nm + pad))
```

to

```
rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's', nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, nm.encode('utf8') + pad))
```

worked for me, because type(nm) was 'unicode', while type(pad) str.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Win7 and Pythonxy.
I had to edit the file `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_carchive.py` lines 84-85, and change     `nm + pad` to `str(nm + pad)`

original:

```
rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's',nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, nm + pad))
```

Fix:

```
rslt.append(struct.pack(self.ENTRYSTRUCT + repr(nmlen) + 's',nmlen + entrylen, dpos, dlen, ulen, flag, typcd, str(nm + pad)))
```